# Splunk log4j2 plugin not working in mule application

Tags: mule, log4j2, splunk

I have a requirement to send all mule logs to splunk, so for this i am using splunks Http Event collector mentioned here http://dev.splunk.com/view/event-collector/SP-CAAAE6M

for this i have configured appender in log4j2 xml file as

```
     <Http name="SPLUNK"
                 url="https://localhost:8088"
                 token="4B916A8F-C41E-4DD3-80AC-778D3E24F45C" batch_size_bytes="0"
                 batch_size_count="0" batch_interval="0" disableCertificateValidation="true">
                 <PatternLayout pattern="%m" />
             </Http>

 <Logger name="splunk.log4j" level="INFO">
             <AppenderRef ref="SPLUNK" />
         </Logger>
```

i have added following libraries in pom file

```
 <dependency>
             <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
             <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
             <version>1.7.25</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
             <version>1.7.25</version>
         </dependency>
```

i know for this to work i need to add splunk jar in /lib/boot so i have copied following jars in /lib/boot

```
 /lib/boot/splunk-1.5.0.0.jar
 /lib/boot/splunk-library-javalogging-1.5.2.jar
```

but even after that when i deploy to standalone server i get following error but surprisingly it works fine in Studio and not in standalone server.

```
 2017-12-11 14:26:12,771 WrapperListener_start_runner ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLog4jAppender for element Http.
 2017-12-11 14:26:12,771 WrapperListener_start_runner ERROR Null object returned for Http in Appenders.
 2017-12-11 14:26:12,775 WrapperListener_start_runner ERROR Unable to locate appender "SPLUNK" for logger config "splunk.log4j"
```

does any one know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR Unable to locate appender "SPLUNK" for logger config "splunk.log4j"
```

This means there is no `Appender` named "SPLUNK" configured. Make sure your `log4j2.xml` contains such configuration, for example to output log to console:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="SPLUNK" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

See the [Configuring Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Appenders) and [Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) doc for details.

Comment: If you see my original post appender with name splunk is configured in log4j2.xml file `<Http name="SPLUNK"
                 url="https://localhost:8088"
                 token="4B916A8F-C41E-4DD3-80AC-778D3E24F45C" batch_size_bytes="0"
                 batch_size_count="0" batch_interval="0" disableCertificateValidation="true">
                 <PatternLayout pattern="%m" />
             </Http>`

Comment: From your example it does not seem to be under `<Appenders>...</Appenders>` element, is it?

Comment: Yes it is. Anyways i found out the problem its with mule runtime. thank you anyways.

Comment: Great, you can post your solution so it can help others

Comment: There is no solution for it. problem is http-io jars which are bundled in mule are not compataible with the one which are required by splunk-library-javalogging so in order to make it work compaitable http-io jar needs to be /lib/opt folder of mule.